# How do I make my selenium script return all elements instead of only ONE?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

new to python and have started with small web scraping projects. And I have now tries to scrape this [url](https://www.elpriskollen.se/sv/Avtalssida/?ellevid=236&postnummer=18164&forbrukning=20000&avtalId=31792&prevContractTypeId=20).

I want to collect the information in the blue and white boxes. More specifically, the price (536,25) and the name of the provider (Cheap Energy AB), and I would like to collect the top 3, like in the picture below.[image]

The problem is that the output I get is only for the top alternative:

`536,25 öre/kWh, Cheap Energy AB`

The output I would like is :

```
536,25 öre/kWh, Cheap Energy AB 
544,45 öre/kWh, Vattenfall AB
544,45 öre/kWh, Vattenfall AB
```

My code is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

s = Service("/Users/brustabl1/lpthw/chromedriver")
url = "https://www.elpriskollen.se/sv/Avtalssida/?ellevid=236&postnummer=18164&forbrukning=20000&avtalId=31792&prevContractTypeId=20"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)

# Presses the buttton asking if you are an individual or company

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cookie-customer-type"]/div/div/div/div[3]/nav/ul/li[1]'))).click()


lists = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div')

for list in lists:
    price = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div')
    name = list.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/p[1]')

    print(price.text, name.text)
```

I have tried some things, the first is to put a dot in front of the // for the find_element.( `'.//'` ) but the script doesn't like that. the output I get is :

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div"}
```

And right now, I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

1. First of all this XPath `//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div` is matching 1 element only so your `lists` is actually getting 1 element.
2. You have to improve locators.
3. And add the delay. Only when elements you want to put in `lists` are visible you shout collect them.
   This code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.elpriskollen.se/sv/Avtal/?avtalstypid=20&forbrukning=20000&postnr=18164'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.modal-content li.customertype.privat'))).click()
panels = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'panel-body')))

for panel in panels:
    price = panel.find_element(By.XPATH,".//div[contains(@class,'epk-list-price')]//div[@class='epk-list-cell']")
    name = panel.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//p[@class='epk-avtalsinfo'][1]")

    print(price.text, name.text)
```

And this is the output:

```
536,25 öre/kWh Cheap Energy AB
544,45 öre/kWh Vattenfall AB
544,45 öre/kWh Vattenfall AB
```

Comment: thank u; it works indeed. I just need to ask you how to find the more specified Xpath that you provided in the example with the price. What is the methodology? Did you find it in chrome directly?

Comment: You need to **learn** how to create correct locators. There are a lot of tutorials for that. I can't point on any specific one since I learned this issue long time ago and from many origins.